# How to use expo kit in react native init?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera, create-react-native-app

I have used create react native app tool to create initial setup of the my app. With CRNA i used Expokit also. After ejecting CRNA into react-native init setup i couldn't use expo camera features. I'm getting below error while launching app in simulator ("undefined is not an object(evaluating 'ExponentConstants.linkingUri)"). How resolve and use expokit after the eject the application?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [react-native-unimodules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unimodules/core)

> If you create a React Native project through **react-native init** or with
>   another tool like **ignite-cli**, then you’ll need to add the
>   **react-native-unimodules** package to your project and configure it
>   first: follow the instructions in the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unimodules/core).

See detail at [expo blog](https://blog.expo.io/you-can-now-use-expo-apis-in-any-react-native-app-7c3a93041331).

Answer (score 0):

After you eject from `create-react-native-app` you need to use Git or another version control tool to go back. You can create a new project with `create-react-native-app`, copy over your JS code, make sure it works, and then eject and this time choose the ExpoKit choice.

Comment: I couldn't use ExpoKit in react-native init. This is the problem i'm facing currently.

Comment: I don't understand your question or the state of your repo. The CRNA documentation explains how you can create a new project and eject to ExpoKit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible yet, according with this answer in the Expo Forumn: https://forums.expo.io/t/react-native-init-expo-sdk/1903/2